# Reactive form pattern validation not working properly on array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have multiple input text field for inputting domain names in a reactive form. On hitting enter, the value will be pushed to the form control which is an array. I want to apply pattern validation on each item in this array using regex whenever a new value is added.

But this is not working as expected as seen here in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpc1jg

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Enter "com". The form will become invalid. But, if I enter "google" next, the form becomes valid.
2. Enter "google" first, then enter "com". The form is valid for both the input.

If "com" is an invalid value, I want the form to be invalid whenever "com" is entered. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the default validator is not working properly with arrays. Maybe you should create your own validator.

I build a quick solution working around the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zku8h7

*app.component.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ng-select class="disable-arrow" 
  [items]="[]" 
  (change)="valueChanged($event)" 
  [addTag]="true"
        [multiple]="true" [selectOnTab]="true" [isOpen]="false" placeholder="Enter domains"
            formControlName="domains">
        </ng-select>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
    Values: {{form.value | json}}
<br>
    Errors: {{form.valid | json}}
```

*app.components.ts*

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

     this.form = this.fb.group({
        domains: [[]]
      });

 }


valueChanged(value) {
  const last = value.length;
  const valueStr = value[last - 1];

  if (!valueStr.match(/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/)) {
    value.pop()
    this.form.patchValue({
           domains: value
      })
 }
```

Another solution is to use 
this.form.valueChanges().subcribe( arrayValues => code to modify depends on the result)

Also, the pattern is not right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting Corrupted Content Error in stackblitz.